# Can I make python interact with a non existent display, or think there is a 2nd one

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to simulate having a 2nd monitor, and allow for pixel-location based clicking on that 2nd display (off screen for my actual display)

I need to run a combination of pyautogui, and selenium chromedriver, in a non invasive area.  Ideally, that would be completely off screen, on an equally sized simulated 2nd monitor.

lets say I had some automation I needed to run, but only a single machine (with no vmware capabilities) to run it on.

I also needed to watch a meeting on the screen, while the automation is running.

I set the meeting to be on my display, and the clicking automation to run on a simulated 1920 x 1080 display 2.

Is this possible via python?

Comment: Which libraries are you using? Are you talking about Tkinter? PyGame? PyQt? Python-GTK? Something else? What do you mean by "some automation"? Are you using PyAutoGUI? Selenium?

Comment: pyautogui and selenium chrome driver.

Comment: I think your best bet is going to be to use Selenium in headless mode.

Comment: selenium headless might solve some issues, but not all.  A lot of the automation involves scrolling, and also image recognition.  It needs to be able to "see" the area to search.